# Why am I not getting labels of my tf.data.dataset in the correct order when using the tensor flow map function and turning it to a numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

So I'm creating a tensor flow dataset with the image_dataset_from_directory method. The thing is, I want to split the tf.data.dataset returned by this function in two numpy arrays of both input data (trainX) and labels (trainY). For this, I use two simple functions to get the data and call them later with the tensorflow map function. Also, I turn tf.data.dataset given by the map function to a numpy array. All mentioned is in the code below:

```
def get_inputs(inputs, labels):
    return inputs
def get_labels(inputs, labels):
    return labels

trainX = np.concatenate(list(train_ds.map(get_inputs)))
trainY = np.concatenate(list(train_ds.map(get_labels)))
```

Then, I plot the images with the following code:

```
def view_image(trainX, trainY):
    image = trainX
    label = trainY
    
    
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))
    
    for i in range(8): #9
        ax = plt.subplot(4, 4, i + 1)
        plt.imshow(image[i].astype("uint8"))
        plt.title(int(label[i]))
        plt.axis("off")

view_image(trainX,trainY)
```

I was expecting this outcome:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TZpAw.png)

Instead, I got this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XPt7j.png)

1s and 0s are my labels. My question is: Why am I not getting my inputs correctly labeled when plotting? (I'm sure originally labels were assigned in the right order)